# codefluent prevent get for property

Tags: c#, codefluent

I have two entities:

1. categories
2. products

And  There is a `1:n relationship` between them so I can get all products in a category by: 
`Category.Products`  However, I don't want this property to **exist**. This, because the category is `chached` and if i load the products this way they wil also remain in the cache.

I can load the products by `ProductCollection.LoadByCategpory` and that is fine.

> How can I prevent the property Products to be part of a Category? I assumed setting 'Hasget' to false would do the trick but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `IsModel` property to false on the entity property "Products". It means "model" layer producers (as opposed to "persistence" layer producers) should not declare this property. Note this is only partially supported, as it can have side effects on other producers, so make sure it works well in your context.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am using only the BOM producer (C#) and SQL azure producer. Anything that I should look into?

Comment: You should be fine AFAIK

Comment: Hmmm, had problems with the BOM producer for one property. All other ~50 properties I removed did not give any probems. A reference to SetProducts was still produced by the BOM in the CopyFrom function of the Category.

            if ((dict.Contains("Products") == true))
            {
                this.SetProducts(CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.ConvertUtilities.SplitToDictionary(((string)(ConvertUtilities.ChangeType(dict["Products"], typeof(string), null))), ',', true));
            }